# 4k Monitor out of sync after wake-up from energy saving mode

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, intel-graphics, 4k-resolution

**CORE SYSTEM:**

- Intel Core i7-4790 3,6 GHz
- 8 GB RAM
- Windows 8.1 (latest Updates)

**GRAPHICS AND MONITORS:**

- Intel HD Graphics 4600 - Latest Intel Driver (16.3.2015, Version 10.18.14.4170)
- Main Screen: ASUS PB287Q - 4K (3840 x 2160)
- 2nd Screen: ASUS VS24A (1920x1200)

**PROBLEM:**

When the monitor is waked up from energy saving mode, then all movements on the 4K monitor are "lagging behind". The mouse cursor feels slow, like being "sticky". Dragging a window is slow, and during movement, windows also appear as being split into two halves.

I don't know the exact reason, but possibly the refresh rate is out of sync.

*EDIT:* The OSD of the monitor says that it is always running on 60Hz.

**CURRENT SOLUTION:**

Monitor needs to be turned off and on again, then it works. Seems like the driver is getting a refreshment signal due to monitor power-off-on.

*EDIT:* It also works when doing some change on the driver, e.g. turn the picture left, then back again. So in fact it is a software/driver problem.

**QUESTIONS:**

- Can the driver be configured that the lagging problem does not happen?
- If that is not possible, is there at least some command or shortcut which resets the driver, like it does after turning off and on the monitor ?